# Thread throws an exception in the middle of serialization?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Is it possible that for a given thread if it throws an exception that it will bubble to the `Main Thread`?

e.g,

**Serialization code**

```
using (Package package = Package.Open(stream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
     using (var xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Normal))
     {
         var rsm = new XpsSerializationManager(new XpsPackagingPolicy(xpsDoc), false);
         DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource) flowDocument).DocumentPaginator;
         rsm.SaveAsXaml(paginator);
         rsm.Commit();
     }
}
```

Where inside the `SaveAsXaml` it iterates to the to the `DocumentPaginatorSource`'s `GetPage(int pageIndex)`.

What happens if a given `thread` executed the `SaveAsXaml` and it throws an `Exception` while iterating in it? Will it continue to iterate to the `Main thread`?

`SaveAsXaml` is something I don't have control over but I know that it tries to execute `GetPage(int pageIndex)` and complete the serialization by completing the number of pages it has to serialize.

Answer (score 1):

No exceptions never automatically move from one thread to another. Certain APIs such as Task.Wait acts as a rendezvous point where marshalling of the exception happens, but it doesn't happen automatically.

If a thread throws an exception that isn't handled, the default behavior of the .NET runtime is to terminate the process due to an unhandled exception.

Comment: I expect it to be like that but according to the logs that was generated it looked like it jumped from the second `thread` to the `main thread`. What's happening is that `main thread` is also executing a serialization and `second thread` is also executing the same method but the `UI` controls are created on its own `dispatcher thread` so it shouldn't affect each other.

Comment: I concur with Brian, exceptions never magically jump threads. If you run similar code on the main thread and the background thread, maybe you just got confused and the observed exception _really_ was thrown on the main thread.

Comment: I'm not saying it did magically jump threads from the exception but if an exception is thrown and say you are doing `Coroutines` where the `thread` thrown an `exception` will it continue to execute on a different thread?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you observed is that when an exception goes unhandled in .net, the runtime takes down the whole AppDomain as a safety measure.

So unhandled exception in a background thread == app crash.

This has changed slightly in .net 4.5 whereas unobserved exceptions in *Task* are ignored (previous behavior can be opted in).